# Is there an inverse factorial expression I can use in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, math

I want to edit this to get `numberOfCircuits` on its own on the left. Is there a possible way to do this in MATLAB?

```
e1=power(offeredTraffic,numberOfCircuits)/factorial(numberOfCircuits)/sum
```

The math for this problem is given in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61755/is-there-a-way-to-solve-for-an-unknown-in-a-factorial, but it's unclear how to do this with Matlab's functionality.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61755/is-there-a-way-to-solve-for-an-unknown-in-a-factorial) question provides the math you need to solve your problem.

Comment: @JamesKPolk, problem with mathematicians is that they assume that infinity is within hand's reach;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak:  :) you have to use numerical methods even with these answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a math, rather than programming, question.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, I don't agree. Part of it is maths, but the question is, "is there a possible way to do this in matlab"? And the answer is not trivial, even if one figures out the math (see my answer below). (You can still vote for VLQ;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak this wasn't clear from the question. Updated and voted to reopen.

Comment: Btw I don't see anything unclear in the answer on the link - it lays out the algorithm just fine.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, OK, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the easy part is rearranging:

```
fact_to_invert = power(offeredTraffic,numberOfCircuits)/sum/e1;
```

Inverting can be done, for instance, by using `fzero`. First define a continuous factorial based on the `gamma` function:

```
fact = @(n) gamma(n+1);
```

Then use `fzero` to invert it numerically:

```
numberOfCircuits_from_inverse = fzero(@(x) fact(x)-fact_to_invert,1);
```

Of course you should round the result for safe measure, and if it's not an integer then something's wrong.

Note: it's **very bad practice** (and brings 7 years bad luck) to name a variable with a name which is also a built-in, such as `sum` in your example.

Comment: "Luck is a habit to see and seize opportunities" so it cannot be affected by some random events :^)